# Use 'Shift + Caps lock' instead of 'Caps Lock'

Tags: windows, keyboard

I have a Japanese keyboard at home on which the Caps Lock functions differently to the standard UK/US keyboard.
To toggle Caps Lock you need to use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> which pretty much eliminates setting it accidentally.

Is there any way to set up the same behaviour on a UK/US keyboard for my work PC. 
I'm using Win XP Prof.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In autohotkey:

```
CapsLock::Return
+CapsLock::CapsLock
```

Though you could then set Capslock itself to a much more useful function rather than disabling it entirely. You could have it equal to shift, for example:

```
Capslock::Shift
```

or set it to open/switch to Firefox:

```
Capslock::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
IfWinExist, Mozilla Firefox
{
IfWinActive, Mozilla Firefox
{
Send ^t
Send !d
sleep, 100
Send ^a
}
WinActivate
WinWaitActive
}
else
Run %programfiles%\Mozilla Firefox 3.1 Beta 3\firefox.exe
return
```

(Though the latter would need a tiny bit of configuration for FF's path, and how long you need the sleep to be)

Comment: Is that the version of firefox you're using or does it not update the directory name when it updates itself? :)

Comment: Rightio :) (15 characters? What is this :()

Comment: Oh! Somebody merged it all for me! How nice <3 RCIX, it is indeed that FF doesn't update it's directories - running the latest 3.5 stable :P (Though I do get updates a few days early because I'm still apparently a "beta tester", but it's never given me trouble :)

Comment: An additional point is that AHK comes with a compiler, to make portable executables, so you don't need to install AHK itself, though it did seem to need elevation under win7, and doesn't work in elevated applications in vista unless it's also elevated. XP it'd work fine, though.

Comment: I just tried the +CapsLock::CapsLock but it didn't work.  I have CapsLock::Escape defined, and doing shift+capslock still triggers an escape.

Comment: Aha.  swapped the ordering so that the +CapsLock was defined first and that fixed it.

Comment: Just remapping like that actually sends {Blind}Capslock - which explains why esc was interfering :P

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) for this

```
+CapsLock::CapsLock
CapsLock::return
```

Comment: ... and so much more too

Answer (score 1):

The small free application [CapsUnlock](http://www.brainsystems.com/capsunlock/) does this fine.

> CapsUnlock supersedes the locking
>   mechanism of the CapsLock key and thus
>   prevents the accidental turning on of
>   CapsLock. It runs as a little tray
>   application in the taskbar. The user
>   can select an override option, which
>   allows CapsLock to be switched on and
>   off by holding down the left Shift key
>   while pressing CapsLock.

Answer (score 1):

I use [SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/) and map my Caps Lock to be a mute button on my PCs. I use it all the time now.

Answer (score 0):

I hated accidental caps until I came across this:
[ihATEtHEcAPSlOCKkEY](http://www.ihatethecapslockkey.com/)

Comment: Thanks T. This let's me disable Caps Lock but not toggle it though.