# Mapping "Caps Lock" function to some key, after remapping "Caps Lock" key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, capslock, windows-key

In the spirit of [this awesome question](https://superuser.com/questions/333445/simulating-the-windows-key-on-an-old-keyboard), if I've remapped the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key itself to be the <kbd>Win</kbd> key, can I somehow map some key or combination to the "Caps Lock" functionality? In case I ever wanted to actually lock caps again? I think <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> would be great.

I'd like to be able to do this via the registry (see link above), as opposed to installing something. I understand that there are [lots](https://superuser.com/questions/419854/how-can-i-toggle-caps-lock-when-the-caps-lock-key-is-remapped) [of](https://superuser.com/questions/566520/binding-caps-lock-key-to-another-unique-key) [solutions](https://superuser.com/questions/1193/reassigning-the-caps-lock-key-on-windows-or-os-x) [already](https://superuser.com/questions/38323/use-shift-caps-lock-instead-of-caps-lock) [out there](https://superuser.com/questions/381296/mapping-caps-lock-to-escape-and-control-on-windows-7), but I don't see one suggesting a registry or app-free solution.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yeah, I'm asking basically the same thing, but I'd like to do it without any further S/W (even SharpKeys). I'll edit my question to reflect this emphasis.

Comment: That same answer that suggests SharpKeys also points out that it's just a GUI wrapper for the registry remapping way, which is mentioned (and a tutorial linked to) in that existing answer.

Comment: I saw that, and the HowToGeek article referenced twice in that answer was really great. However, the scancode link in that article is dead. I was thinking the registry-only answer should be collected here, but I can go with the other one instead. I'll just post a comment with a live scancode link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa299374(v=vs.60).aspx